# Remote access Raspberry PI 3 from Mobile Application

Tags: remote, pi-3b+

I want to Remote access my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B from my Mobile Application(that i have created). Actually I have many Devices at home that based on Raspberry PI (many Raspberry PI) and want to control from one Mobile application without Port forwarding.

I also referred **[Dataplicity Documenation](https://docs.dataplicity.com/)**, but it's give different command for different Raspberry PI, so i can't bind those in one mobile application.

1. how can I distinguish between different Raspberry PI during passing command via Cloud ? (if i use Cloud).
2. How should I authenticate my incoming command(data) on Raspberry PI for security purpose ? (Is it coming from my Application only).

Thanks in Advance for your Suggestions and Helps. Actually, I am software Engineer and beginner in Communication Part, So if you can't understand Actual Task/Situation(it's my bad), then please let me know. I explain a Task in more detail so hopefully you understand well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raspis (lots of them) <-> register to a "central raspi" with (little programm/server selfwritten or so) tasks which handle all that fancy sending and receiving stuff <-> mobile application which gets current possible tasks/options from the central raspi and displays only available stuff

and i would just go for a basic rsa authentification // ssh connection unless you want to share that app and give more users access to it ..

so you would just need to handle that auth on that one raspi <-> mobile app

and could build a closed network for the other raspi's and that central one :p

or you could build a socket connection between your app and that raspi but .. if its just sending commands there wouldnt be needed as you just would execute a script with some parameters on the central raspi via ssh -c :p

Comment: First of all Thanks for your Reply. As I understand that you mean, I need one Raspberry PI as a central Server and and it will medium of my communication between other devices and Mobile Application. That's true and would be great help if you can provide me some links.